# Replacing null value with a 0 in an Update query or better reccomandations if any

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have an update to add a column current integer to another column's integer but if that other column's integer is a null then I want it to just add first column to zero.

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE ATable SET BoxQuantity = ATable.BoxQuantity + (Select sum(BTable.BoxQTY) FROM BTable Where PartNumber Like Bolt%'", con)
```

If there are no bolts in BTable then I want it to just add zero and not get an error due to a null value, how would I go about doing this?

```
UPDATE ATable
SET BoxQuantity = ATable.BoxQuantity +
                 (Select sum(BTable.BoxQTY) FROM BTable Where PartNumber Like Bolt%')
```

Comment: coalesce((select...), 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE ATable
SET BoxQuantity = ATable.BoxQuantity +
                 (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(BTable.BoxQTY), 0)
                  FROM BTable WHERE PartNumber LIKE 'Bolt%')
```